# How to pause work in particular thread running in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, threadpoolexecutor

In my app I start multiple media downloads in `Threads` via `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Now I want to be able to pause particular download threads. How I can do this?

Comment: are you  keeping track of your **Futures**

Comment: I gonna leave an answer now. but I'm doing loads of guesses as I don't know the internal of your code.

Comment: ok, i've edited my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

well I'm not sure how you have implemented your code, so I'm just guessing here.

One way of doing this, by keeping track of your Threads,

for example create a Map :

```
Map<String,Thread> threads=new HashMap<String,Thread>();// ensure each Thread has a unique id, in this case its supposedly a String. then you can control them from outside your thread pool.
```

here is a hacked implementation:

```
public class hello{

public static void main(String...strings )throws Exception{

     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
     Map<String,Thread> threads=new HashMap<String, Thread>();
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         Thread t = new myRunnable((i+1) +" ");
         threads.put((i+1)+"", t);
         executor.execute(t);
     }

     Thread.sleep(2000);
    ((myRunnable)threads.get("1")).isSuspened=true;
}

private static class myRunnable extends Thread{
    String a;
    public  boolean isSuspened=false;

    public myRunnable(String a) {
        this.a=a;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            if(isSuspened){
                continue;
            }
            try{
                System.out.println(a);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
}
```